# Mail is sent without the attachment

Tags: php, email, attachment

I have this code, working it but mail is sent without attachment. Attachments 
in /files directory.

http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/1273/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script didn't attach the file. The correct way to do it is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#105661

Just implement this function in your script and it should work.

Comment: Implemented this function but not work. Please, can you give a sample?

Comment: Here is another much simple example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#69129
get this function and just append to email variable the result of the function. Should work ...

Add $email .= addAttachment($file_name);
Before calling mail( ... line 177

Comment: That means you have an error. Look in error log files. Don't forgot to add the function at line 164 in contact_send.php

Comment: Not work. Please you can this functions on my code file?

Comment: Here is the modified part: http://pastebin.com/nAErtHgt

You should be able to understand what is happening and why is working/notworking. Here is not on a freelance site :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing the point of the script. Yes it sends an email but it isn't meant to attach a file to the email. It is only supposed to upload the given file to a directory on the server it is on.

> Creat a file contact.php and put the code from the --- contact.php --- then create a file contact_send.php and paste the code from --- contact_send.php ---. Just put on you`r server and just www.site.com/contact.php. the banners will be saved in the file FILES. please put in the contact_send.php on: $destinatar = "MAIL HERE"; you`r mail to lock like this: $destinatar = "mail@mailserver.com"; . Enjoy :D

He mentions here (in one way or another) that the file will be saved to

```
[SCRIPT LOCATION]/files/[FILE]
```

Comment: Well, but how can send email with attach?

Comment: Like @Sacx said, take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#105661

Comment: Implemented this function but not work. Please, can you give a sample?

Comment: How are you calling the function?